# Is a meagre set discrete?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

A set $S$ in $X$ is defined to be discrete if $\forall s\in S$, $\exists$ a neighborhood $U$ s.t. $S\cap U={x}$. "Typically, a discrete set is countable". I wonder if there exists any non-typical cases.

(Delete: It could be proved that a zero-measure set is discrete) It could be proved that a zero-dimensional manifold is discrete, and from my intuition, a discrete set does not has to be meager or zero-measure (?). I would like to know if a meager set is definitely a discrete set.

(In the context of Euclidean space, Lebesgue measure, for now)

Comment: A measure zero set is generally not discrete. Same for meager sets. They are small but not so small as to be discrete.

Comment: A zero-masure is not necessarily discrete. For example, $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero.

Comment: @Ian You are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: Is your question abour $\mathbb{R}$ or an arbitrary metric (or even topological) space? Do you mean the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Adayah $\mathbb R$ for now. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$, the Cantor set is meagre, but not discrete.

Comment: (Upvote) Is discrete set generally meagre or zero-measure,then?

Comment: @HighGPA In $\mathbb{R}^n$ discrete sets are both.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ discrete sets are countable, hence meagre and zero-measure.